# Why does this throw acces violation exception?

Tags: c++, oop

This line of my code throws the exception :
(Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation.
this->v was 0x443E112)

```
v[i] = v[i - k];
```

In the function below :

```
void NagyEgesz::eltolJobbra(int k) {
        this->n = this->n + k;

        for (int i = n-1; i >= k ; i++) {
            v[i] = v[i - k];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            v[j] = 0;
        }
```

And here is the declaration of the class :

```
class NagyEgesz{

    int *v;
    int n;
    int elojel;

public:

    NagyEgesz();
    NagyEgesz(int elojel, int n, const int* szamjegyek);
    NagyEgesz(const NagyEgesz &x);
    ~NagyEgesz() {
        delete v;
    }
    void kiir();
    void eltolJobbra(int k);
    NagyEgesz osszead(const NagyEgesz &x);

};
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The code you gave is not complete. You don't show for example where you allocate the `v` array.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a loop in a reverse order:

```
for (int i = n-1; i >= k ; i++) {
```

And therefore you should replace `i++` with `i--`

Tip to discover similar problems in future: `write access violation` often means typos in array indices